# Complex Projective Space as a Quotient of a Disc

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, projective-space

I am reading [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATch0.pdf) and I have a problem understading how the complex projective space $\mathbb CP^n$ can be realised as a quotient of $D^{2n}$ (page 7)

Let me briefly outline his arguments (or what I make of them):

1. $\mathbb CP^n=S^{2n+1}/\sim$ where $x\sim \lambda x$, $\left|\lambda \right|=1$.
2. $S^{2n+1}=\left\{(w,a\sqrt {1-\left|w\right|^2})\in \mathbb C^n\times \mathbb C: \left|w\right|\le 1, \left|a\right|=1\right\}$, $S^{2n-1}=\left\{(w,0)\in \mathbb C^n\times \left\{0\right\}: \left|w\right|=1\right\}$
   $D^{2n}_+=\left\{(w,\sqrt {1-\left|w\right|^2})\in \mathbb C^n\times [0,+\infty):\left|w\right|\le 1\right\}$.
3. "Each vector in $S^{2n+1}$ is equivalent under the identifications $v ∼ λv$ to a vector in $D^{2n}_+$ , and the latter vector is unique if its last coordinate is nonzero. If the last coordinate is zero, we have just the identifications $v ∼ λv$ for $v ∈ S^{2n−1}$"

My problem is with Step 3, I do not see how this implies that the two quotient spaces are homeomorphic.

Here is my idea: Consider the map $S^{2n+1}-S^{2n-1}\to D^{2n}_+$,
\begin{equation*}\left(w, a\sqrt{1-\left|w\right|^2}\right)\mapsto \left(\frac wa,\sqrt{1-\left|w\right|^2}\right)\end{equation*}
Then, starting from $S^{2n+1}-S^{2n-1}\coprod S^{2n-1}$ we can first go to $S^{2n+1}$ (via the identity) and then to $\mathbb CP^n$ (call this composition of maps $f$) or first to $D^{2n}_+-S^{2n-1}\coprod S^{2n-1}$ and then to $D^{2n}_+$ (by the identity) and finally to $D^{2n}_+/\sim$ (call this composition of maps $g$) . $f,g$ are both continuous, have the same domain and make the same identifications. If I could show that they are open then by a general Theorem, the quotient spaces would be homeomorphic.

However, I do not think it should be that complicated; Hatcher must have something else in mind. Is there a general principle for quotient spaces that I am forgetting?

Comment: The crucial thing is that all spaces we deal with here are compact (quasicompact and Hausdorff). So any continuous bijection between two of these spaces is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @DanielFischer But the sphere with the equator removed isn't compact...

Comment: Don't remove the equator. If $Q$ is the quotient space of $D^{2n}_+$ with respect to the restriction of the equivalence relation, the composition $$D^{2n}_+ \hookrightarrow S^{2n+1} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{C}P^n$$ factors through $Q$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh my, it was really simple. I was trying to construct a map from the sphere to the disc, while the converse is much simpler...